# How to add subpages to a page in wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress

I want to add several new tags/subpages/sub-contents (I don't know what it is called) like this one:
http://www.rle.mit.edu/gg/publications/#1456759349089-640f1dcb-938f

【publications】is a page in which there are 【2016】,【2015】,...

When I hit 2016, the relative contents show up.
How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: That is a post date archive. First you will have to be using the post_type post or have date archives enabled on a custom post type. You will then have to call the information or use a WP menu. But based on what you have provided I have no idea what your site is capable of.At least add a link to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from looking at the demo you've given, you're talking about an accordian.  Try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/tabby-responsive-tabs

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this but it doesn't work as I expected. The parent page shows nothing. Only when I spell the right link ~/publications/2016, will the child page 2016 shows up.

Comment: Here is another plugin that you could use https://wordpress.org/plugins/accordion-shortcodes/

Comment: Thank you! 【tabby-responsive-tabs】--- This is what I want!

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna do it yourselve, copy this into your file:

```
<script>
function pshow(id){
document.getElementById(id).style.display="block !important";
}
function phide(id){
 document.getElementById(id).style.display="none !important";
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:pshow('p1')">Show p1</a>
<a href="javascript:phide('p1')">Hide p1</a>
<p class="hide" id="p1">This is p1</p>
```

Add this under design> customize css

```
.hide{display:none !important;}
```

Comment: Thanks. But could you elaborate this... Copy this code to which file? I know little about this.

Comment: The place you wanna have this sliders

Comment: Thank you. It seems like what I want without plugins. but it is weird. http://fding.xyz/contact/

Comment: Im traveling -> no computer. But you could try adding !important. Edited example